# Loop through slice of unknown length

Tags: go

Below is a code sample to get started. The idea is I am making an API endpoint so I do not know the length of the slice I am to parse. How would I iterate through an array in Golang with an unknown length so that it does not error out "Index out of Bound" or crash?

```golang
package main

type Human struct {
  ID    int64
  Name  string
  email string
  alive bool
}

func main() {
  var human []Human

  // add the loop here
}
```

Comment: This is a slice, not an array. https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/16

Comment: @adarian while the length of a slice might be unknown at *compile time*, at *run time* it can be discovered using the built-in function `len`. So there is nothing that stops you from using the classic for loop form, i.e. `for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {`, without causing index-out-of-bounds errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @tkausl and @Cerise Limón

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

var pow = []int{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128}

func main() {
    for i, v := range pow {
        fmt.Printf("2**%d = %d\n", i, v)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t understand how this answers the question. Please see if you can clarify/expand the answer.

Comment: @CarlWinbäck the key part is the 'range array' on the right of the loop it returns 2 items (index, value) which you can then use in your loop